# VMware tools for Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization, vmware-tools

When will VMware publish a version of VMware tools for Ubuntu 10.10?

The small screen is killing me.

Comment: I gather that VMWare themselves have a rough idea as to when it is ready. Just out of interest, have you actually ever though of not upgrading your OS until you're certain all your software works okay under it? I've only _just_ gone to 10.04 and that was after exhaustive testing to ensure I wouldn't stuff up my wife's Windows VM. Of _all_ my customers, she is the most demanding :-) And, was it _really_ necessary to put that advert in your question?

Comment: I think your question belongs to http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 6):

You can install the open version of the VMware tools through apt-get. From a fresh install of Ubuntu 10.10, just do this:

```
apt-get install --no-install-recommends open-vm-dkms
apt-get install open-vm-tools
```

That should get your screen resizing, clipboard, file drag-and-drop, etc. running.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. This installed it for me but I can't get screen resizing. Do I need to run any configuration?

Answer (score 4):

I installed VMware tools "manually" as described [here](http://ubuntuguide.net/install-vmware-tools-on-ubuntu-10-04). The guide is for 10.04 but it will also work in 10.10:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo mount /dev/cdrom /media/cdrom
cp /media/cdrom/VMware*.tar.gz /tmp
sudo umount /media/cdrom
cd /tmp
tar xzvf VMware*.gz
cd vmware-tools-distrib/
sudo ./vmware-install.pl
```

Comment: I tried this on my install of Ubuntu 10.10, and it tells me that the modules won't work with my version of the kernel - so then it tries to build said modules against my kernel header files, but always detects the header files version as "@@VMWARE@@ UTS_VERSION".  I think the script is broken (VMWare 6.4).  Now upgrading to VMWare 6.5 to see what happens...

Comment: Sorry, that should have been VMWare version 6.5.4 and 6.5.5, not 6.4 and 6.5...

Comment: I had the same problem of not able to resize the screen (with resolution). This answer solves my problem.